# Circular dependency? Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django

I have a strange issue. While loading a Django site, i get this error:

```
Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found
```

The reverse is properly defined

```
urlpatterns = patterns('main.views', url(r'^$', 'home'),)
```

The view exists

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html', {}, 
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now the problem is this -> home.html makes use of a NavigationMenu template tag that tries to execute reverse('home') again. This being circular reference, and the above error is thrown.

I can make the code work fine by skipping 'home' in NavigationMenu creation. But what is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: try name your pattern `urlpatterns = patterns('main.views', url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse only works with [named url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns). You need to do:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('main.views',
    url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),
)
```

in order to do:

```
reverse('home')
```